# Call std::visit with passed lambdas

Tags: c++, c++17, std-variant

I have a struct that contains a `variant`.

I want to write a member function for that struct that should run code depending on which type variant currently holds.

However, I have issues making it compile.
I don't want to use more "template shenanigans" like using a separate struct to define `operator(T&)` since it pollutes the syntax even more.
Here is an example:

```
struct Data {

std::variant<int, double> var;


//Into this function,multiple lambdas should be passed for cases that the user wants to handle
template<typename ... Funcs>
void apply(Funcs&&... funcs) {
    std::visit(std::forward<Funcs>(funcs)...,var);
}
};
int main() {
    Data d;
    d.var = 4;
    //variant holds int and lambda provided that takes int&, execute it:
    d.apply([](int& i){
        std::cout << "I am Int Poggers" << std::endl;
    });
    d.var = 0.0;
    //variant holds double but no lambda passed that takes a double, hence nothing happens:
    d.apply([](int& i){
        std::cout << "I am Int Poggers" << std::endl;
    });
}
```

and I even don't know what the compiler wants from me:
https://godbolt.org/z/oM4584anf

Comment: `std::visit` operates with a _singular visitor_, and calls this visitor with _the active member of the supplied variant(s)_, discovering the correct handler by using overload-resolution semantics (which allows conversion to occur). With all that in mind: if you want only a single overload from a lambda to be selected, you will need to write some type that defines `operator()` for the terms you don't want. Also be aware that your `std::visit` call is incorrect since `std::visit` doesn't accept multiple visitor functions (though this is not the cause of your problem)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that `std::visit()` needs a "visitor" that must handle **every** type of the `std::variant`.

> However, I have issues making it compile. I don't want to use more "template shenanigans" like using a separate struct to define operator(T&) since it pollutes the syntax even more.

There is nothing complicated.

You can simply add a trivial struct (with deduction guide) as follows (and as proposed in the [cppreference `std::visit()` page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit))

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts...
 { using Ts::operator()...; };

template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```

Then, given that you want that your `std::visit()` return `void`, you can add, in your `apply()` method, a generic-do-nothing lambda

```
template<typename ... Funcs>
void apply(Funcs&&... funcs) {
    std::visit(overloaded{ // <-- pass through overloaded
               [](auto const &){}, // <-- and add this generic lambda
               std::forward<Funcs>(funcs)...},var);
}
```

Now the first `apply()` call

```
d.apply([](int& i){
    std::cout << "I am Int Poggers" << std::endl;
});
```

should compile calling the supplied lambda because is a better match (given that `d` contains an `int`) and the second call compile calling the do-nothing generic lambda, because the generic lambda is a better match for a `double`.